# Как объединить 2 датафрейма по значениям?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть 2 датафрейма:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |

и

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 2 | y |
| 10 | z |

Как объединить датафреймы так, чтобы значения(b) из 2-го датафрейма попали в значения 1-го по совпадению колонки a, если будет значение a, которого нет в 1 датафрейме, то его не добавлять?

Вот как будет выглядеть итог:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 2 | y |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно обойтись обычным маппингом:

```
df1["b"] =  df1["b"].map(df2.set_index("a")["b"]).fillna(df1["b"])
```

теперь df1:

```
   a  b
0  1  x
1  2  y
2  3  3
3  4  4
```

Comment: А если индексы и 1 датафрейма и 2-го будет вразнобой??

Comment: Не важно. Маппинг делается по колонке a

Comment: Просто я подумал, что по индексу. На самом деле у меня есть 2 датафрейма, но в поле 'a' не 1 2 3 4, a рандомные числа. И таким методом уже не получается.

Comment: Тогда приведите в вопросе оригинальные датафрейм.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1389640/ сформулировал в новом вопросе, спасибо.