# Объединение датафреймов по значению столбца

Tags: python, pandas

Есть 2 датафрейма:

| number | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 374 | 1.0 |
| 556 | 2.0 |
| 448 | 3.0 |
| 345 | 4.0 |

и

| num | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 444 | 2.5 |
| 556 | 4.0 |
| 345 | 7.0 |
| 219 | 5.0 |

Используя:

```
df1["weight"] = df1["weight"].map( df2.set_index("num")["weight"] ).fillna(df1["weight"])
```

все остается как было.
Вот как должен выглядеть итог:

| number | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 374 | 1.0 |
| 556 | 4.0 |
| 448 | 3.0 |
| 345 | 7.0 |

К сожалению код ниже тоже не работает:

```
d1 = {'number': [374,556,448,345], 'weight': [1,2,3,4]}
d2 = {'number': [444,556,345,219], 'weight': [2.5, 4, 7, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
df[['number']].merge(df1, how='left').combine_first(df)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

```
new_df = df[['number']].merge(df1, how='left').combine_first(df)

>>> new_df
     number  weight
0      374     1.0
1      556     4.0
2      293     3.0
3      345     7.0
```

p.s. перед этим я переименовал столбец *num* в аналогичный, как в df1, то есть *number*

Comment: Выводит значения weight 1-го датафрейма, не работает, добавил код ниже, в вопросе.

Comment: так присвойте переменной этот код) и все заработает) исправил

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: *Если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.*